# Django. Применяться стили только после перезагрузки браузера

Tags: css, python, django

в настройках:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

в шаблоне

```
`{% load static %}`
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

при изменении кода в CSS файле и сохранении, на сайте происходят изменения только тогда, когда перезагрузишь браузер, а иногда и просто не применяются, с чем это может быть связано ?

Comment: Заметил, что так происходит пока что только в Google Chrome

Comment: С кэшем браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перезагружайте браузер с очисткой кэша. Например, командой ctrl+f5.